# Boundedness of a set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $$S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + 2hxy + y^2 =1\}$$

For what values of $h$ is the set $S$ nonempty and bounded?

For $h = 0,$ it is surely bounded, the curve being the unit circle. What for other $h$?

Please help someone.

Comment: For $h=1$ it is not bounded

Comment: You didn't specify whether $(x,y)\in\mathbb R²$ or $\in\mathbb C^2$ (or anything more exotic).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** You may rewrite 
$$
x^2 + 2hxy + y^2 =1 
$$ as
$$
(x+hy)^2 + (1-h^2)y^2 =1
$$ to see that the elliptic case comes when
$$
1-h^2>0.
$$

Comment: can you elaborate please?I mean how do you say 'elliptic case comes when $1-h^2>0$'?

Comment: @ramanujan If $1-h^2>0$ then the equation is of the form $X^2+Y^2=R^2$ which resembles the equation of a circle/an ellipse, otherwise you have $X^2-Y^2=R^2$ which is rather the equation of an hyperbolic curve.

Comment: @olivierOh! I got it...Thank you

Comment: @ramanujan You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$x^2+2hxy+y^2-1=0$ is a conic, and it is an ellipse if its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant_classification) $B^2-4AC=4(h^2-1)$ is negative.